# Disable drag ghost image when dragging on html5

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I am working on a drag and drop code with the native html5 Api  (even if it's not that great yet). I researched, but all I find is how to change the ghost image. I don't want to change it, but remove it completely. What should I do? Thanks a lot for taking your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible yet.

**Alternative way**: replace it with a transparent image.

Comment: Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this is to set an "empty" `span` as the drag image. It seems that the element can't be truly empty, so the `&nbsp;` is required.

```js
let dragElement = null;

const dragStart = (event) => {
  // remove the element if it exists
  if (dragElement) {
    document.body.removeChild(dragElement);
  }

  // create an empty element
  dragElement = document.createElement("span");
  dragElement.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
  dragElement.style.position = "absolute";
  dragElement.style.left = "-1000%";

  // add the element to the dom
  document.body.appendChild(dragElement);

  //set it as the drag image
  event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragElement, 0, 0);
};

const dragEnd = (event) => {
  // when we have finished dragging, 
  // remove the element from the dom
  document.body.removeChild(dragElement);
  dragElement = null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
element.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
   e.dataTransfer?.setDragImage(new Image(), 0, 0);
});
```